# How to open this .DB file?

Tags: database

I have a few database files with .db extension and I want to take a peek. However I don't know what program should I use to open the files. I've found a similar quesiton that says checking the header of the db file could reveal the name of the database-program/type.
What I've found is "FLDB".
Anyone have any clue what kind of database file can this be?

Edit:

Trying to give more hint:
This is a program of a car navigation system and it knows 8 languages. I'm trying to localize it to my language. There are lots of .db and two .gdb files witch (probably) contains this data.

Comment: How did you get the .db file? if you tell us where it came from it may give a clue on how to read it.

Comment: This .db file is part of a car navigation program. I'm trying to translate the labels etc, localize.

Comment: Which car naviagtion system? there may be toolkits out there for that system, or people who have worked with it before. But if people have to guess what system your using you are less likely to get experienced help. Also don't fall in to the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), Your `X` is "*How do I go about localizing my GPS in to my language, I think I can do it this way...*" but you are asking `Y` "*How do I read this database format*". Edit your question and type out and ask your `X` and explain what you have tried so far to accomplish `X`.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/

Answer (score 21):

I don't think there is a way to tell which program to use from just the .db extension. It could even be an encrypted database which can't be opened. You can MS Access, or a sqlite manager.

**Edit:**
Try to rename the file to .txt and open it with a text editor. The first couple of words in the file could tell you the DB Type.

If it is a SQLite database, it will start with "SQLite format 3"

Comment: I checked it in total commander. The first few lines should give away the type, as you suggested. Thats how I found out the "FLDB" name.

Comment: Maybe "Fileset Location Database"

Comment: That was my guess(google's guess) and I tried to download an IBM database server to open it... no luck so far.

Comment: How can I tell if the database is encrypted?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to tell if it's encrypted.

Comment: An encrypted database, if well encrypted, should show a uniform byte distribution. That means that every possible value of a byte (0-255) should show up with comparable probability.

Comment: Following the last comment in this answer, on a *nix box you can try `file *.db` which returned for me: `....db: SQLite 3.x database, last written using SQLite version 30160`

Answer (score 7):

You can use a tool like the [TrIDNet - File Identifier](http://mark0.net/soft-tridnet-e.html) to look for the [Magic Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) and other telltales, if the file format is in it's database it may tell you what it is for.

However searching the definitions did not turn up anything for the string "FLDB", but it checks more than magic numbers so it is worth a try.

If you are using Linux [File](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_file.htm) is a command that will do a similar task.

The other thing to try is if you have access to the program that generated this file, there may be DLL's or EXE's from the database software that may contain meta information about the dll's creator which could give you a starting point for looking for software that can read the file outside of the program that originally created the `.db` file.

Comment: I tried with TriDNet and it says "Unknown!"
Thanks for the tip though.